# I wrote a loop in MIPS but for some reason it keeps running infinitely?

Tags: mips

I'm writing this code for class, but for some reason even after I reach the limit of the loop the code keeps running infinitely hoping someone can see why it is doing that. msg2 is just a prompt to enter an integer and numbers is an array, and $s0 is the number of elements in the array (e.g if its 6, ask for 6 inputs from user before terminating). (this is just a snippet of the code everything is in the main class)

```
    numbers:     .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

     la    $a0, msg1            
     li    $v0, 4              
     syscall
     li    $v0, 5
     syscall
     move  $s0, $v0        
     slt   $t1, $s0, 12
     beq   $t1, 1, fill_loop

    fill_loop:

    li    $t2, 0
    la    $a0, msg2            # $a0 = address of msg1
    li    $v0, 4               # $v0 = 4  --- this is to call print_string()
    syscall
    li    $v0, 5
    syscall
    sw    $v0, numbers($t2)
    addi   $t2, $t2, 1
    beq   $t2, $s0, print_loop
    j     fill_loop
```

Comment: You're only showing a fragment of the code, so, for example, we cannot verify what is in `$s0`, or, where `print_loop` is.

Comment: Ok I added the background info for where I'm getting $s0, as for now print_loop is empty it just causes the program to exit (li  $v0, 10) is what I have for now

Comment: Regardless of anything else, you can't use `sw $v0, numbers($t2)` when you're only incrementing `$t2` by 1 for each iteration, since `sw` requires the effective address to be word-aligned.